# Sending SMS from AWS SNS from the same phone number without Sender ID.

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns, sender-id

I'm in Canada and our app is publishing different SMS. For example, we can send a test SMS to the user, we send SMS alert on different events, etc...

I see from this list that Canada does not support Sender ID: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html. So in result, the SMS is sent from a random number.

Is there a way to tell AWS SNS to always send our SMS from the same number?

Answer (score 1):

By default, SNS will sent your SMS using a shared pool of numbers. Canada is one of the countries supported by this shared pool. This is why you see your SMS getting sent from different numbers each time.

If you purchase an origination identity ([P2P long codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-long-codes.html) are easy to setup, cheap, and are supported in Canada), your SMS will all be delivered from this number.

You can also specify which origination identity you'd like to use as part of the Publish call if you have multiple identities available. If you don't specify which number to use, SNS will automatically load balance between the numbers you have available.

Comment: +1, but according to [the SNS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/), SNS does *try* to always use the same sender number when sending messages to a given recipient.